# HTTP Post file to webserver failure

Tags: php, http, post

From our offline application we want to post an xml file via HTTP Post to our webserver. This worked fine but when the xml is larger then 650KB the post failed.

The PHP settings on our webserver:

- memory_limit **128M**
- post_max_size **32M**
- upload_max_filesize **16M**

Somebody knows what the problem could be?

**UPDATE**

I've tested something on our webserver. I made a form with a textarea and paste the XML in the textarea. When I submitted the form I didnt get any results of the POST I echoed but when I paste the half of the XML I get the results.

Strange thing is I didnt got an error message when posting the whole XML.

Comment: Please show me you error message , how much spaces are remaining in your folder ?

Comment: Also you should show the code (or part of it) so it becomes clear *how* you are sending the HTTP POST request.

Comment: I dont get an error message in our offline application. We have enough space remainen to receive the XML.

Comment: @hakra The code in our offline application is written in Omnis. This is the part that posts the file HTTPPost (lvHOST,'/gateway/xml.php',lvList,'') Returns lvSOCKET HTTPRead (lvSOCKET,lvResult) Returns %charcount HTTPClose (lvSOCKET) Returns %status

Comment: There are two things that I would look into - it may be a network issue - i.e. try doing the post from the same webserver itself. It may go through on localhost where it wouldn't otherwise if some network device is limiting post sizes. Also if you're using apache, check if the `LimitRequestBody` directive is set as that could also create issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this at the top of php file that you call on form submit:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Maybe your connection is too slow to send that file in allowed execution time of php script.

Answer (score 0):

Run phpinfo() and check if these variables are what you think are. Maybe some .htaccess or other webserver configuration file is overwriting them. Also check if there's no connection timeout.

What response do you get from server when post fails?

Comment: The phpinfo() is exact the same as the variables I thought.

Comment: I don't get any response. Even if I trie to post a form with a textarea with the XML in it I don't get a response. If I decrease the XML I get a succesful post.

Comment: Is data sent correctly by your application? Maybe it's the app who can't handle too big POST.

Comment: Yes its send correctly. XML with smaller size worked well. And as I say, when i'm posting a textarea with the large XML in a PHP script on my webserver it doesnt work either but I don't get an error (smaller XML files worked well on the webserver.

Comment: I already know that with small XML is everything fine, I asked if bigger XML is sent correctly? Does it leave the client? What does apache and php logs say about this? Do server receives data and is not responding or it doesn't receives anything?